# YouTubePlayerSupportFragment cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android

I am using ADT eclipse to develop android app. I imported and using android-support-v7-appcompat support library and while using "YouTubePlayerSupportFragment" class it is erroring out saying unresolved.

Min SDK for my app is 7.

Can anyone please help which support library should I use to use youtube player API for lower versions of Android. ?

I have gone through all support libraries and features added in that library, but I didn't find any clue.

Can anyone please help?

Piece of code I am using

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment fragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.sample_video, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
fragment.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, new OnInitializedListener() {
....
}
```

Comment: how are you trying implement it? post your code :)

Comment: Have you properly imported jar file for Youtube API???

Comment: @jycr753 I added piece of code which is throwing errors

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA I didn't add Youtube API jar file. Won't these classes come when we add support library?

Comment: Did you added to the compile build jars?

Comment: I added YouTubePlayerAPI jar manually in libs folder and it is now working fine.  Thanks for your help @jycr753

Comment: Thanks for your help @PiYusHGuPtA. I thought the classes will automatically get added to library like other classes ,Fragment etc are doing when we add support library