# Android Studio: canot import com.google.android.youtube

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube-api

I got the jar file and also pasted it in lib folder of my project. Got the API key , and also wrote compiling code but still cannot import com.google.android.youtube

```
dependencies {
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev157-1.21.0'
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency: compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar') have two occurrences in your gradle file. Also edit the dependency: compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev157-1.21.0' to compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev181-1.22.0'. You can find more information [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3). After updating the gradle file, build your project once again.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it is not solved , same issue

Answer (score 0):

I found here an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7048) about Android Player API of YouTube. The issue is all about YouTube APIs should have support via gradle and a documentation of it. I found here in this issue that one of the community created a [github](https://github.com/tommus/youtube-android-player-api) on how to add YouTube Android Player API into Android application via Gradle. So you may look on this on how to use it.

For more information, check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957344/issue-with-android-studio-youtube-imports-youtubeplayersupportfragment-cannot).

Comment: It shows error in this part "compile 'com.github.tommus:youtube-android-player-api:1.2.1'"