# YouTubePlayerSupportFragment cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube, android-youtube-api

I'm unable to get the `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` correctly compiled into my project. I've reviewed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957344/issue-with-android-studio-youtube-imports-youtubeplayersupportfragment-cannot) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898390/youtubeplayersupportfragment-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type?lq=1) and have implemented the suggestions there, but still no luck.

Here is what I have tried so far: I have the YouTube API saved in my libs folder. The dependencies section of my gradle file looks like this. You can see that I've tried to include the library using gradle. Whether I comment this line out or not (and sync, of course), I still have the same result.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'

    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'

    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'

    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8.2'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
//    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev149-1.20.0'
}
```

Here is a screenshot to show how I have the YouTube API saved in the `libs` folder. [image]

I followed the instructions from the [Google Developers guide](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3?hl=en) to download the zip file and understand which jars needed to be copied over. These instructions include the following:

> Dependencies for all Platforms
>
> The following are the jars from the libs folder required for
>   applications on all platforms: 
> google-api-client-1.20.0.jar
>   
> google-oauth-client-1.20.0.jar 
> google-http-client-1.20.0.jar
>   
> jsr305-1.3.9.jar 
> google-http-client-gson-1.20.0.jar (when using GSON)
>   gson-2.1.jar 
> google-http-client-jackson2-1.20.0.jar (when using
>   Jackson 2) jackson-core-$2.1.3.jar 
> google-http-client-jdo-1.20.0.jar
>   (when using JDO) jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar 
> Android Dependencies
>
> The following are the jars from the libs folder required for android
>   applications or a newer compatible version of each dependency:
>   
> google-api-client-android-1.20.0.jar (for SDK >= 2.1)
>   
> google-http-client-android-1.20.0.jar

Finally, I looked at the project structure, and it looks great here:

[image]

So why doesn't this thing resolve to a type? I'm completely at a loss. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: did you add this to your `build.gradle` -> `repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}`

Comment: Yes. As you can see, I have many dependencies in this project, so I'm confident that the underlying structure for this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have included the wrong YouTube SDK.

`YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` is part of the YouTube Player API package, that you can find here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Just download the `JAR` archive, put it in your 'libs' folder, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Well, that would make a difference. Thanks!